# Application not able to access SD card when WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is granted at run time

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

In **android M**  to access sdcard has to force stop and start app manually when permission is granted at runtime, how to achieve it programmatically?

However sdcard can be accessed if the app is force stop and restarted.

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE


     /* **Checking permission **
        if doesn't have request
         else
         browse file directory       
    */

    String[] perm = { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };
    if (checkSelfPermission(perm[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {


                    requestPermissions(perm, REQ);

                } else {

                    Explore(); //method to browse file directory
                }
```

**onRequestPermissionsResult**

```
   @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {  

   //Not able to browse SD card until restart application


       Explore(); //method to browse file directory


    } else {
        Log.i("onRequestPermissionsResult", " Request denied");
    }

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Comment: I have created library for it. It is easy to use by simple steps. https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/Ask-Permission

Answer (score 9):

You will need to restart the application to obtain the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission (an some other permissions). This is because this permission is actually a Linux permission. The latest preview version of Android does not restart the application in this case, but maybe Google will add this later.

You could use this code to do the restart:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    // Write external store permission requires a restart
    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
        if (Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.equals(permissions[i]) &&
                grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Restarting application");

            // Schedule start after 1 second
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    getIntent(),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, pi);

            // Stop now
            System.exit(0);
        }
}
```

Edit: you can find a list of Android permissions which are associated with a Linux permission here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/etc/platform.xml

Comment: Tried this with zero milliseconds delay and it still worked, so perhaps there is no need to be concerned about a (very unlikely) race condition in which the Alarm goes off before the System.exit(0) completes.  Anyway, I'm using your 1000 millisecond delay for extra insurance.

Answer (score 0):

You can below condition to check whether SDCard is available or not

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
        android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

 //Check for the file
 File appFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
            + context.getString(R.string.app_name));

 boolean exist = appFolder.exists();
}
```